# DNS forward and reverse lookup works in Terminal, yet vCSA 6.7 site does not load in any web browser

Tags: dns, browser

I am hosting a local site on my LAN (update: I'm seeing that this *might* be something specific to **VMware vCSA 6.7** so I added that info). I can access it from my Mac and Windows machines, but for some reason it does not load in a web-browser on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. I have a home lab that I use for IT studies, so DNS is being provided by two Windows Server VMs (I use VMware vSphere, if it matters). Also, DHCP is running on the Windows AD servers. Again, Windows (non Domain-joined and Domain-joined) *and* Mac clients are getting DHCP leases with the proper DNS server settings and lookup works as expected on other machines.

Here is the output of PING shortname & PING FQDN (`-c 4` so 4x) and HOST commands on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. **Worth noting: when I ping "shortHostname" it resolves...but when I ping the FQDN it does *not* resolve...unsure why**:

```
sam@LenovoThnkPad:/$ ping MyTest-Site -c 4  
PING MyTest-Site.MyLab.local (192.168.3.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from MyTest-Site.MyLab.local (192.168.3.11): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.12 ms
64 bytes from MyTest-Site.MyLab.local (192.168.3.11): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.40 ms  
64 bytes from MyTest-Site.MyLab.local (192.168.3.11): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.91 ms  
64 bytes from MyTest-Site.MyLab.local (192.168.3.11): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2.28 ms  

--- MyTest-Site.MyLab.local ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.913/2.181/2.403/0.190 ms

sam@LenovoThnkPad:/$ ping MyTest-Site.MyLab.local -c 4
ping: MyTest-Site.MyLab.local: Name or service not known

sam@LenovoThnkPad:/$ host MyTest-Site  
MyTest-Site.MyLab.local has address 192.168.3.11  

sam@LenovoThnkPad:/$ host MyTest-Site.MyLab.local  
MyTest-Site.MyLab.local has address 192.168.3.11
```

Adding output of `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf` as requested:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Highlight the pasted text from the terminal and format as `code` using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: What does the hosts line  in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file look like? Does it have the [!UNAVAIL=return] before the dns (as supplied by the libnss-resolve package?

Comment: Thanks, @ubfan1. Not seeing that string, no. Added `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf` to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added my FQDN entry to `/etc/hosts` and this fixed the issue:

```
adminMe@IdeaPad-Ubuntu:/etc$ cat hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   IdeaPad-Ubuntu
192.168.1.121   vCSA6-7.myLab.local

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```